# RestKit PUT with object name

Tags: objective-c, json, rest, restkit

I'm working on an Application which interacts with a Webserver written in Java.
The Service works with the RestKit Framework on my iOS Application.

JSON String **from** Server

```
{"object":{"value":"key"}}
```

JSON String **to** Server

```
{"value":"key"}
```

Sending from the server to the application works with the objectname in front, but the way from app to server does not work, because the object name is missing.

Is there a way to add the ObjectName to my RestKitMapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out myself:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider registerMapping:objectmapping withRootKeyPath:@"objectname"];
```